# Why does Chrome remove extension's icon when in 'incognito mode'?

Tags: google-chrome

I have an extension installed in Google Chrome named : ***Proxy-Switchy***.

It has an icon just next to the right of address bar to the left of popular (single) settings icon which looks like:

[image: icon shown]

But when I switch over to Incognito Mode, it disappears and it becomes like:

[image: icon missing]

Why does it happen so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe Chrome when in incognito mode removes your extensions to sandbox your incognito mode browser session from your extensions.  Ie. your extensions have access to your chromium browsing data.

Please correct me if I am wrong.  I cannot seem to find the link I read this on at the moment.

Comment: Just found in the chromium blog about the sandboxing technology which provide strong isolation between web content, extensions, and the browser. Extensions run in a separate operating system process from the browser kernel and from web content, helping prevent malicious web sites from compromising extensions and malicious extensions from compromising the browser kernel.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to explicitly enable Extensions in Incognito mode

[image: Chrome extensions]

This behaviour is by-default - for the reasons [Chris explains](https://superuser.com/questions/211145/why-does-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode-removes-extensions-icon/211147#211147).

Comment: Thanks for the observation I just checked that it happens so.